# MSBuild Delete in csproj does nothing

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I try to use MSBuild to delete some files in the OutDir but it never works. I have to use an Exec instead.

```
  <Target Name="ResetPackages" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">
    <Exec Command = "del /Q /F $(OutDir)*.extension/>
    <Delete Files="$(OutDir)*.extension" />
  </Target>
```

The Exec command works while Delete does nothing. Can anybody explain me why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an ItemGroup to `Delete` if you want wildcards to be expanded:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Test">
     <ItemGroup>
       <_FilesToDelete Include="$(OutDir)*.extension"/>
     </ItemGroup>
     <Delete Files="@(_FilesToDelete)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

(The Exec-Task runs `CMD.EXE` which then does the wildcard expansion.)

Comment: Thank you I just found out it works with:
  <Target Name="ResetPackages" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyFiles Include="$(OutputPath)*.extension" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(MyFiles)" />
  </Target>
Thank you anyway for your answer